# How to hide footer for PDF document created in BIRT engine 4.2.1

Tags: birt

Is there any way to hide grid component in footer based on page number in BIRT reports for PDF format? I set following code segment in grid's visibility property. It appears that pageNumber value does not set ? Any suggestions?

```
 <VALUE-OF>pageNumber</VALUE-OF> % 3  == 0
```

**Solution :**

Can be done using "onRender" method. Used following code in grid component

```
<method name="onRender">
<![CDATA[
    if( pageNumber % 3 == 0 || pageNumber % 4 == 0 ){
        this.getStyle().display = "none";
    }
]]>
</method>
```

Comment: http://www.birt-exchange.org/org/forum/index.php/topic/28949-different-master-page-header-on-the-first-page-of-report/page__pid__114846__st__0&#entry114846

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the script like this `onRender`

```
if(reportContext.getOutputFormat()=="pdf"){
        ****your script/code****
}
```